# Display JSON multi-dimensional array in Spring

Tags: arrays, json, spring

Struggling to display JSON array in below format using Spring Controller.

```
[
    ["Apple","Red",[100,10]],
    ["Orange","Orange",[150,8]]
]
```

I am using Jackson library.

My controller is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/fruits")
public class FruitController {

    @RequestMapping(value="{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Fruit getLocationInJSON(@PathVariable String id) {

        Fruit fruit = new Fruit();

        fruit.setName("Apple");
        fruit.setColor("Huningue");
        fruit.setNumbers(new String[]{"100", "10"});

        return fruit;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance,

Selvaraj

Comment: what did you try so far

Comment: {"name":"Apple","color":"Red","numbers":["100","10"]}

Comment: can you share your controller?

Comment: How to share my code to you? I get error while sharing!

Comment: @AmerQarabsa I have share the controller!

Comment: What do you mean by "display"? Where and how are you trying to display the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

The format you are trying to achieve is not applicable in java, see java does not support array of several types, you can have either array of strings or array of arrays but you cannot have array of both strings and arrays

Comment: Thank you very for the reply and the clarification for my question.